# Apache と node.js の連携でURLパスを付加したい

Tags: node.js, apache

下記の通り、Apache + node.js の連携でパスを付加するとエラーが発生します。
私はどのようにすれば連携に成功しますか？
よろしくお願いします。

---

scotch.io の tutorial で node.js を勉強しています。

- Getting Started with Node, Express and Postgres Using Sequelize
  https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize

何となく仕組みが分かったつもりで、本番環境に合わせて Apache 2.2 と連携してみました。
ルートではなくパスを付加してみました。

**conf/httpd-proxy.conf**

```
<Location /scotch>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

チュートリアルにあるように ttp://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todosに向けての POST は成功します。

ttp://127.0.0.1/scotch/api/todos だとエラーが返ってきます。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST //api/todos/</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドキュメントに

> もし第一引数が / で終端するならば、第二引数も / で終端すべきです。逆もまた然りで、第一引数が終端しないならば、 第二引数も終端すべきではありません。 これに反すると、バックエンドサーバ向けに変換されたリクエストは 必要なスラッシュを欠く可能性があり、バックエンドサーバは期待する結果を返しません。 
>   --[mod_proxy - Apache HTTP サーバ バージョン 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ja/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

とあるのがまさにこれでは無いでしょうか。

試していないので推測ですが

```
  <Location /scotch/>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  </Location>
```

or

```
<Location /scotch>
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000
</Location>
```

or

```
<Location /scotch>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000
</Location>
```

あたりのいずれかは求める挙動になるのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさにこれでした。node.jsの方を疑って色々と原因を探っていましたが、入り口であるApacheの方を先に疑うべきでした。